# bairisch <===> boarisch

Tags: pronunciation

Die unterschiedliche Schreibweise (bayerisch, bayrisch, bairisch) mit ihren Bedeutungen wird hier im Netz zwar hinreichend erklärt, doch bisher habe ich noch nirgends etwas gefunden, was erklärt, warum es 'boarisch' heisst.

Comment: An sich ist die Frage falsch herum gestellt: Es müsste eigentlich heißen, warum die hochdeutsche Transkription für das mundartliche Wort *bairisch* ist. Übrigens heißt das nicht überall "boarisch".

Answer (score 4):

Es ist ein typisches Merkmal der bairisch-österreichischen Dialekte, dass dem althochdeutschen Diphthong /ei/ der Diphthong /oa/ entspricht, z.B. in einem Wort wie *hoazn.* Im Gegensatz dazu hat das Bairisch-Österreichische auch ein /ai/, das dem althochdeutschen langen /iː/ entspricht, z.B. in einem Wort wie *raitn.* In der Standardsprache sind diese beiden Laute zusammengefallen, so dass nun die Wörter *heizen* und *reiten* dasselbe /ai/ aufweisen. Ähnlich wie im Bairisch-Österreichischen ist die ursprüngliche Unterscheidung aber in vielen Dialekten erhalten geblieben, augenfällig etwa im Alemannischen, das den alten Lautstand bewahrt hat mit *heize* vs. *riite.*

Da nun der Laut im Wort *Bayer* auf altes /ei/ zurückgeht, so ist die Form *Boar* die normale Entwicklung im Bayrisch-Österreichischen.

Answer (score 0):

Weil im Dialekt Worte manchmal anders gesprochen werden, als sie in Hochsprache gesprochen oder geschrieben werden.

In vielen Teilen Bayerns schreibst man Hase, und sagt "Hos"oder schreibt "Hose" und sagt "Husn". Der Münchner schreibt München und sagt "Minga".